# OdbcConnection DataName and DataSource not found

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, odbc, datasource

I am using ASP.net to create a web app. I use `OdbcConnection` to connect to `MySQL`. But it seems to create the object but not it doesn't fill up the datasource and dataname fields. I have the famous error

> [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Here is my code failing:

```
OdbcConnection MyConnection;
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=test;" + "UID=debug_user;" + "PASSWORD=password;" + "OPTION=3";
MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
MyConnection.Open();
```

I also use to have a connectionstring in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="UTRN_DB_ConnectionString" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Database=cjr_db;Server=localhost;UID=cjr_db_user;PWD=password;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have the driver set in my Data Source Administrator with `MySQL`. I've uninstall and reinstall everything. I keep getting this error. I Just don't understand why I get this error while I still specify everything (port, etc...) in the connection string and it keep failing

EDIT:
Here is my `web.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="UTRN_DB_ConnectionString" connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Database=cjr_db;Server=localhost;Uid=cjr_db_user;Pwd=password;providerName=(System.Data.Odbc)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and this is how i read it:

```
string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UTRN_DB_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string conString2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UTRN_DB_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (OdbcConnection connection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(conString2))
{
connection.Open();
...
}
```

Comment: You're missing `providerName="System.Data.Odbc"`

Comment: I jsut tried to do this, it didn't change anything.

Comment: The connection string in the `web.config` is different to the one in your code.. Is that because you want to connect to different DB? Why don't you read it using `ConfigurationManager` class

Comment: I tried both way actually, and even reading it, it let, in my object Myconnection, empty fields in Database, DataSource and Driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my problem here:
[tadaaaam](http://dacosta9.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application/)
Basically, you have to seek the difference of your 64bits and 32bits installed on your machine. By default VS is seeking for the 32. And in your ODBC Sources Manager it shows up the 64.
So you either configure your project to seek for the 64 **OR** install the 32 bits version of MySQL ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string must contain Provider and Data Source as:

```
string MyConString = "Provider=(Data Provider);Data Source=(Path of source file)"
```

Comment: What source file are you referencing to ?

Comment: I am referencing to the complete path of my data source file say "C:\myDatabase.accdb"

Comment: I don't use microsoft access

Comment: What ever you are using: The problem is your ConnectionString only.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but how is it that, i specify everything in my connectionstring, but it can't fill up the fields with the informations ?? Because the field ConenctionString in my object MyConnection take the string i parse (either from web.config, or my conString). But doesn't fill the other fields.

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/)

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/) as well.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005?

Comment: I'm using the version 6.01

Comment: whose version is this? Is it of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 6.01
I also have the Native Client 10.0 and 11.0

Comment: Then why are you using Odbc ADO Objects? I mean you may use SQLConnection Object instead of OdbcConnection? Seems like I am not able to solve your problem otherwise. Sorry!

Comment: Because it needs to be portable. I don't have the choice. I know, it's working with a MySQLConnection. But I am not allowed to choose to use this.

Comment: I recommend this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise its my time to leave.

Comment: Yes, already tried this one too. Well thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have some spelling mistakes in your connection string in the `web.config` file. It should be `Driver` instead of `DRIVER`, `Pwd` instead of `PWD`, `Uid` instead of `UID` and so on. 
Please change your code to the one below

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not using SQL Server, but an ODBC connection
EDIT: I still used your spelling, but still bugging

Comment: The code is just an example amend it to your requirements

Comment: Still didn't change anything

Comment: Can you update your code and show us how you're reading the `connectionString` from the `web.config` file

Comment: You don't need the `()` around `providerName=(System.Data.Odbc)`